# Find Next DateTime of a Regular Event

Tags: c#

Is there a simple way in C# to find the `DateTime` value of the next occurrence of a regular event?

For example, if I have an event that occurs every Wednesday at 10:45 am, how can I easily find the `DateTime` of the next occurrence?

The result of the above example should be the first `DateTime` in the future which is a Wednesday at 10:45 am.

Thanks.

Comment: what you are asking about !! Please elaborate more..

Comment: it's better if you clarify more your question and also post some code

Comment: why don't you just add a `TimeSpan` to your `starting date`?

Comment: I've updated my question to try and help out. How could I find that TimeSpan?

Comment: In your given example, you said 'every wednesday', so the `TimeSpan` would be `7 days`

Comment: Please have a look on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If the current time is currently Wed 10:00, should the next event be today at 10:45, or next Wed at 10:45?

Comment: That's a good way around it, thank you! Mr.Nimelo

Answer (score 1):

so, if you like to get next wednesday's date then:-

```
DateTime nextWednesday=DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

while(nextWednesday.DayOfWeek!=DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
   nextWednesday= nextWednesday.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateTime.AddDays(7);` to add a week. You can also use `AddYears()`, `AddMonths()` to add years or months. dateTime in this examples are the instance of dateTime object with the first datetime